# Efficient VueJS use of UI components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am creating a lot UI components for VueJS (such as buttons, inputs) and I don't want to make my code inefficient and slow as I have to import them everywhere all the time. My thinking is that if I do have 10 imports for one component, there'll be 10 components reusing the same code and CSS classes which will make my bundle huge. Is that how it works? And is there a way where I can import them once globally (like any CSS class or global JS function) so that I can just call them from anywhere?

Is it more efficient to try to avoid components for UI Kits by just using CSS classes and HTML, like this for example?:

```html
<input type="text" class="ui-kit-input">

<!-- or for something like a radio -->

<div class="ui-kit-radio">
   <input type="radio">
   <label>Male</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a bundler such as webpack, your code will be bundled once.

When a component imports another module, webpack will check for that file in the bundle.

Css is bundled once as well.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to hear!